# Is it possible to reference a masterpage in an MVC ASCX control

Tags: silverlight, model-view-controller, scriptmanager, ascx

I have an ASCX control that has to render Silverlight dynamically. The dynamic code works in a non-MVC environment, however when I try to load the silverlight into an MVC ASCX, I get a ScriptManager error. However, my main aspx page does reference the masterpage, which has a script manager. I just need the control to realize that there will be a scriptmanager once it is plugged into the main page. I am trying to use a ScriptManagerProxy, but it is still looking for the ScriptManager. So, I think my biggest problem is getting the control to recognize the masterpage from the main page. Hopefully this explains my problem properly. If you need any code snippets, I can provide them

Comment: The problem was more of me being narrow-sighted by another developer's previous work. Silverlight content was being hosted via an <ASP:Silverlight> object, and I had assumed that this was necessary in order for it to be dynamic. However, looking at it closer I saw that I could just as easily use an object tag as is typical for silverlight. This resolved all of my issues surrounding the ability for the content to load.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you should be using ScriptManager with MVC.  ScriptManager is for Web Forms.  There is a 3rd party one for MVC  http://mvcscriptmanager.codeplex.com/.

I don't know that I quite understand what you are trying to accomplish.  But you can use an IFrame (yuck) in your MVC page to display an aspx page.

Comment: I did end up not using the ScriptManager as I had already commented on. Thanks!